# someone please tell me how to get a list of twitter friends handles @twitter in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, twitter

```
NSURL *followingURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/lists/list.json"];

NSDictionary *parameters= [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:account.username,@"screen_name", nil];


SLRequest *twitterRequest =[SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter requestMethod:SLRequestMethodGET URL:followingURL parameters:parameters];

[twitterRequest setAccount:account];

[twitterRequest performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        //DEAL WITH THE ERROR
    }
    NSError *jsonError =nil;
    NSDictionary *twitterFriends = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&jsonError];


    [accountDictionary setObject:[twitterFriends objectForKey:@"screen_name"] forKey:@"screen_name"];
    NSLog(@"%@", accountDictionary);    }
 ];
```

I'm using this code, but my application is crashing. so any further help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: It would be more helpful if you tell where and how it crashes.

Answer (score 0):

You may use this component as a basis. https://github.com/ArchieGoodwin/NWTwitterHelper

To get friends from twitter using twitter username (screen_name):

```
 [[twitterHelper sharedInstance] getFollowers:@"screen_name" completionBlock:^(BOOL result, NSError *error) {
            //here is code
 }];
```

You will get a sample NSString with friends user_id, name, screen_name, profile_image_url in ((twitterHelper *)[twitterHelper sharedInstance]).stringFriends